# How do i give ellipsis in axis labels in d3 v4?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

Here is my code snippet for implementing the ellipsis on x axis labels in d3 v3.
Can someone help me figure out the changes needed to my code in v4??

```
//function for adding '...' if length is more than 50 px
    var wrap = function () {
                     var self = d3.select(this),
                         textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength(),
                         text = self.text();
                     while (textLength > (50) && text.length > 0) {
                         text = text.slice(0, -1);
                         self.text(text + '...');
                         textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength();
                     }
                 };
    //calling the function
    svg.select('.x.axis')
                     .call(xAxis)
                     .selectAll('text')
                     .style('text-anchor', 'end')
                     .attr('fill', '#8a9299')
                     .attr('transform', 'rotate(-60)')
                     .each(wrap);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to save the group element containing x-axis into a variable and use as shown below.

```
var wrap = function() {
  var self = d3.select(this),
    textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength(),
    text = self.text();
  while (textLength > (50) && text.length > 0) {
    text = text.slice(0, -1);
    self.text(text + '...');
    textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength();
  }
};

//calling the function
xAxis.selectAll('text')
  .style('text-anchor', 'end')
  .attr('fill', '#8a9299')
  .attr('transform', 'rotate(-60)')
  .each(wrap);
```

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 250 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .padding(0.1);
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0]);

// append the svg object to the body of the page
// append a 'group' element to 'svg'
// moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = [{
    "salesperson": "Bob Patrickson",
    "sales": 33
  },
  {
    "salesperson": "Robin Dearden",
    "sales": 12
  },
  {
    "salesperson": "Anne Hathaway",
    "sales": 41
  },
  {
    "salesperson": "Mark Wahlberg",
    "sales": 16
  }
];

// format the data
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.sales = +d.sales;
});

// Scale the range of the data in the domains
x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.salesperson;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.sales;
})]);

// append the rectangles for the bar chart
svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.salesperson);
  })
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.sales);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.sales);
  });

// add the x Axis
var xAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// add the y Axis
svg.append("g")
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

var wrap = function() {
  var self = d3.select(this),
    textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength(),
    text = self.text();
  while (textLength > (50) && text.length > 0) {
    text = text.slice(0, -1);
    self.text(text + '...');
    textLength = self.node().getComputedTextLength();
  }
};

//calling the function
xAxis.selectAll('text')
  .style('text-anchor', 'end')
  .attr('fill', '#8a9299')
  .attr('transform', 'rotate(-60)')
  .each(wrap);
```

```css
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```